# How to sort the values in a dataGridView Row Cells[0] so that they were in the same order that textbox.lines[i]?

Tags: c#

> Hello! I have question: textbox text multiline  contains values:
>   Samaccountname1 Samaccountname2 Samaccountname3 etc... dataGridView
>   Row Cells[0] contain the same values but they are located in a
>   different order: Samaccountname2 Samaccountname1 Samaccountname3
>
> Could you tell (if it possible) how to sort the values in a
>   dataGridView Row Cells[0] so that they were in the same order that
>   textbox.lines[i]? dataGridView moved to the form from the Toolbox (not
>   created programmatically).
>   There is such data:
>   [image]
>
> Need to sort here so:
>   [image]

Comment: have you ever tried do by select query which having where condition by order....

Comment: Using binding and something like: row.Cells[1].ToString() + " LIKE'" + textBox1.Lines[i].ToString() + "%'" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the first column in the dataGridView (because using just cells[0]) , try this code may help you :

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

Comment: Thanks. Its Sort all content, but not in the same order like in textbox/